# How to fetch updated data from CMS if using getStaticProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, pre-rendering

I am fetching blog from CMS inside getStaticProps. Now, I have made changes in the blog in CMS but the updated data is not showing up because getStaticProps fetch this data only during `build` time. Is there any way to re-fetch the updated data without `build`?

I only update the blog once or twice in a month and that's why I am feeling getServerSideProps may not be right choice.

I am confused.

I tried researching about it but did not find any answer. For markdown, getStaticProps makes sense as we make changes in the repository and it gets build again, but for CMS, I don't know how to get the updated data.

Comment: Are you looking for Incremental Static Regeneration https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: @Idrizi.A thanks for sharing. I missed this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `revalidate` prop to load fresh data after certain interval ( in your case *once or twice in a month* )

example:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()
 
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 10 seconds
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
```

}

Do keep in mind that if you want [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) (meaning `revalidate` flag for `getStaticProps` explained above) then you need to run Next.js server (`next start` command), without the server there is nothing that could perform requests, update data and generate new static files.

`next export` only generates static files once, with the data that was available at the build time.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking naive question but where/how do I run `next start` command if the website is deployed in vercel?

Comment: @WasimRaja follow this guide https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/configure-a-build#build-command